# How to create a docker image of current file and OS system?

Tags: linux, docker

I wonder if one can take all the current environment variables settings OS applications and create a simple docker layer on top of it all so that docker container user will not be able to damage host system even if he would remove all files, yet will have abilety to access all installed applications and system settings inside his docker layer?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -2):

Technically you might be able to hack together a solution that does this by copying in all data/apps, installing dependencies, re-configuring the applications and providing a bash shell to attach to for a user to play around with but this is not what Docker is designed for at all, not to mention that I would not recommend anyone to attempt this.

I always try to explain docker's usecase as processes which run in isolated containers with defined interfaces that may be exposed. Meaning you would ideally run one application within it which has an interface exposed for communication.

What you are looking for is essentially a VM with snapshots which you can provide to different users.